# Npm module to stream Twitter API content in a Meteor.js app

Tags: node.js, twitter, meteor, npm

I need to make a web app with Meteor.js which allow users to search for a hashtag on twitter and display them in the same page.
I already get the base of the application.

But now, I have a problem. I need to use a npm module to stream the content of the Twitter API.
I've installed that: https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-twitter-api but I don't understrand where I need to put the code.

I've look up for others stuffs, but I don't understand how does it work and how incorporate it in my meteor app.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of including `npm` modules with meteor apps:

1. Using `meteor-npm` Meteorite package. (personally recommended): https://www.npmjs.org/package/meteor-npm
2. Use the native `Npm.require` provided by Meteor to load the package. Documentation: https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#what-about-npm-node-modules

Comment: Thanks, I've done that, but now, I want to stream content from Twitter into my Meteor app. Do you know how to do it ?
I've check some package, but I didn't find a good tutorial or something related to meteor.js